# PL SQL DEV TRIGGER

Tags: триггер, plsql-developer

как я могу задать условие на триггер чтобы он срабатывал только когда модуль в сесссион будет равна
:= 'PL/SQL DEVELOPER'
сейчас он записывает изменение с любого приложение.
спасибо заранее

Comment: Проверяйте это условие непосредственно в триггере. И выполняйте действия только в случае, если оно истинно.

Comment: вот где проверять не могу знать.
использовать when clause не могу

Comment: *использовать when clause не могу* Это ещё почему? правда, использовать надо не "WHEN clause", а CASE statement... или IF THEN statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR X IN (SELECT *
              FROM V$SESSION V
             WHERE V.AUDSID = USERENV('SESSIONID')
               AND V.MODULE = 'PL/SQL Developer')
LOOP
 --код в этом "блоке" исполнится только если сессия из PL/SQL Developer
END LOOP;
```